# can i save a report / form in access 2003 to PDF format?

Tags: ms-access, pdf-generation, ms-access-2003

I know this is easily done in access 2010 by using ConvertToPDF, there is however no option for this in 2003. How did people save to PDF before version 2007 onwards? Also if this could be done without needing to download any extra .dll that would be great, since my organization won't allow me to use them

Comment: You can use PDF printer such as PDFFactory ..

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure Adobe Acrobat is installed on your system.
   Note: You need the full version of Acrobat which is a commercial product, not the free reader.
2. Open Access.
3. Open the database of interest.
4. Open the form, report, table or query that you wish to turn into a .PDF file.
5. Select Print from the File menu.
6. Change your printer name to "Adobe Acrobat" using the drop-down menu.
   7.Click OK.
7. When the "Save PDF File As" dialog box opens, enter a file name for your Acrobat file.
8. Click Save.
9. Open the file using Acrobat Reader and ensure that the process completed successfully.